# Perfectly centering text in round button?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a round button that rotates on hover. As you can see from the animation, the text doesn't seem to be centered perfectly which causes a weird rotation of the `+`.

Here is the code I have:

```css
button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

button:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<button>+</button>
```

Comment: Try using [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) instead of the '+' character. There's all sorts of spacing and what have you associated to a font. It could appear differently for users who are using a set stylesheet, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, would using something like a FontAwesome icon or a Material icon be okay also? Not entirely sure how I would make an SVG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a little hard to exactly center align the text. But it is more easy to center align a shape. So as an alternate option, I created "+" with after and before pseudo elements and it rotates very well. you may check the below code.

```css
button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: transform 2s;
  position: relative;
}
button:after,
button:before{
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
button:after{
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 24px;
  right: 24px;
}
button:before{
  top: 24px;
  bottom: 24px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

button:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, all of the others rely on the horizontal and vertical centring of a piece of text.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```css
button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: transform 2s;
  font-family: arial;
    line-height: 50px;
}

button:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
button:before{
content:"";
}
```

```html
<button>+</button>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Your text stands on the baseline. you can either push it up via a padding equal of average 0.2em or use an inline-block pseudo and vertical-align.

examples below

```css
button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

button:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
button.ib:before {
content:'';
display:inline-block;
height:50px;
vertical-align:middle;
width:0;
margin:0 -0.05em;
}
.pad {
box-sizing:border-box;
padding-bottom:0.175em;
}
p {
text-align:center;
background:yellow;
}
p:after {
content:'';
display:inline-block;
width:120vw;
margin-left:-50vw;
border-bottom:red solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<button class="ib">+</button>
<button class="pad">+</button>
<p> where is baseline ? </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `text-align: center`, `line-height: 50px`, `box-sizing: border-box` and increased the size of plus to make it's movement easy to see.

```css
button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 34px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: transform 2s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

button:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<button>+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` and align the button text horizontally and vertically as

```
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: transform 2s;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

button:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<button>+</button>
```